# HTML: td not 100% table height

Tags: html, css

I've got the following problem:

I have a HTML <table>, which has a fixed height of 100px and no border. Inside this table, I've got one single row (100% height) and inside the row 5 td's (also with a height of 100%).
Inside this td I have a div (position=relative, height=100%).

When I analyze the whole thing with the Chrome dev tool, I see, that the div's height is slightly smaller than the table. How can I set the div's height to be as great as the table?

I've already tried to set the cellpadding to -2px but it didn't work - I'm not really working with tables, so please forgive my lack of knoledge in this area :/

Thank you for your help

Edit: my source code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>text 1</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>text 1</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>text 1</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and the CSS:

```
table{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}

tr,
td{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
}

td > div{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Check padding or margin values.

Comment: Post a complete code example please.

Comment: @Jhecht: all margin and padding values are set to 0

Comment: The  we need to be able to see your HTML, as well as your css. Please edit the question.

Comment: Is this what you're after? http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/j6fjegw8/

Comment: @j08691: No - not really. I realized that cellpadding="0" and cellspacing="0" was the answer - but thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to set cellpadding and cellspacing to 0:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/darekkay/bdej1qgw/